# Django view html to pdf executed twice

Tags: django, pdf-generation

I have following Class to generate a pdf file where I use [django-renderpdf](https://pypi.org/project/django-renderpdf/) to generate a pdf from a html template. But the view is executed twice and an error is thrown.

My class:

```
class WeeklyMetre(PDFView):
    template_name = 'reports/invoice/weekly_metre.html'

    allow_force_html = True
    prompt_download = True

    @property
    def download_name(self) -> str:
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return f"WeeklyMetre_{invoice.invoice_number}.pdf"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        market_labor_specifications = _getWeeklyMetreData(invoice=invoice)

        # calculate reported items: reported market_labor_specifications
        # invoiced specifications which are validated in invoice-period
        # but labor_date before invoice-period

        reported_mls = MarketLaborSpecification.objects.filter(invoice_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'), market_labor__labor_date__lt=invoice.period_from) \
        .values('market_labor__labor_date', 'specification__position', 'specification__name') \
        .order_by('market_labor__labor_date', 'specification__position', 'specification__name') \
        .annotate(sum_pos=Sum('validated_quantity'))

        context.update({
            'invoice': invoice,
            'market_labor_specifications': market_labor_specifications,
            'reported_mlss': reported_mls
        })

        print('context data', datetime.datetime.now())
        return context
```

Between the two excutions I have following error:

```
[01/Feb/2021 07:16:38] "GET /reports/invoice/select/17/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1414
context data 2021-02-01 07:16:44.835695
[01/Feb/2021 07:16:45] "GET /reports/weekly/metre/17/ HTTP/1.1" 200 58063
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60114)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/t3tr4ktys/python-virtual-environments/BillOfQuantities/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/t3tr4ktys/python-virtual-environments/BillOfQuantities/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
context data 2021-02-01 07:16:47.544189
[01/Feb/2021 07:16:48] "GET /reports/weekly/metre/17/ HTTP/1.1" 200 58063
```

First of all I don't know why it is executed twice and on the second execution the user is no more authenticated. At the end the pdf is generated well but I cannot apply the LoginRequiredMixin. More informations will be provided if needed and thank you for any help.

Comment: Is the indentation in your question's code correct? Should `context.update..` be inside `get_context_data`?

Comment: How do you know the view is executed twice?

Comment: What makes you think its executed twice? Can you provide the full output? I don't see the calls to `print('context data', datetime.datetime.now())` showing up.

Comment: Indentation is now correct, just a tipo here. I also updated the error so you can see the print is executed twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you closed tab in browser or browser stopped to accept response from server in some another way. But web server haven't stopped it's renderring and still generates response, but do not have whom to response. That's why you see:

`ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

After that browser does retry with page reload and you see the second request in logs.

So, you need to understand why it happens. See what browser logs and Dev.Tools will show you (statuses, response and etc.).

P.S. About `LoginRequiredMixin` - don't know probably some internal things of browser caused with that "retry", but I believe it still should send cookies and `session_id`.

Comment: I could find a kind of chrome extension pdf.js error and decided to generate the file, save it on the server before download. Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've experienced something like this.

The problem is that when you call your endpoint you call it in the URL without a '/' at the end causing DRF to return 301
that redirects you to the same path but with '/' at the end. The problem with that, that after the redirect you lose your headers and cookies and thus become unauthenticated.

That also explains why you can see 2 calls.

So basically if you have a call like this:

```
api/viewset/dosomethngs
```

to:

```
api/viewset/dosomethngs/
```

Comment: I use <a href="{% url 'WeeklyMetreReport' pk=invoice.pk %}"> Weekly Métré</a> and in my urls.py it is defined as url(r'^reports/weekly/metre/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.WeeklyMetre.as_view(), name='WeeklyMetreReport'),